# How do debug Bot code accessed via DirectLine API?

Tags: botframework

We are developing a bot that will primarily be accessed using the DirectLine API. As the bot and the client app are still in development, the development is made difficult by the fact that we cannot Debug both the client app and bot on one box since DirectLine API can't connect back to the local box.

What's the story there? Any recommendations on best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs#expose).  The basic version is free.

> ngrok allows you to expose a web server running on your local machine to the internet. Just tell ngrok what port your web server is listening on.